# how get amount of post with same tag

Tags: python, api

Currently getting used to python and attempting to use stackoverflows api to query the number of posts with a particular tag.

```
import requests

BASEURL = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/15112125"

params = {
  "site": "stackoverflow"
}

r = requests.get(BASEURL, params=params)

print(r.json())
```

The above code works fine however when attempting to use `/questions/tagged/python` it's unable to get the information regarding the named tagged.

Comment: I can't see any `/questions/tagged/` endpoint in the doc `https://api.stackexchange.com/docs`

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be no `/questions/tagged` endpoint
I think you need to query `/questions` to get a list of all the questions

then programmatically filter them on their tag list (`"tags"` JSON field), see question format here: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question

An example:

```
{
  "tags": [
    "windows",
    "c#",
    ".net"
  ],
  "owner": {
    "reputation": 9001,
    "user_id": 1,
    "user_type": "registered",
    "accept_rate": 55,
    "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a007be5a61f6aa8f3e85ae2fc18dd66e?d=identicon&r=PG",
    "display_name": "Example User",
    "link": "https://example.stackexchange.com/users/1/example-user"
  },
  "is_answered": false,
  "view_count": 31415,
  "favorite_count": 1,
  "down_vote_count": 2,
  "up_vote_count": 3,
  "answer_count": 0,
  "score": 1,
  "last_activity_date": 1549253581,
  "creation_date": 1549210381,
  "last_edit_date": 1549278781,
  "question_id": 1234,
  "link": "https://example.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/an-example-post-title",
  "title": "An example post title",
  "body": "An example post body"
}
```

There is also that endpoint `tags/{tag}/top-askers/{period}` to get the top question askers in a specific tag, either in the last month or for all time. 
See [doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-askers-on-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the questions based on tag the way you are trying, but you may consider using this endpoint which gives you list of questions which are unanswered based on your favorite tags or in case you don't have any favorite tags, it will give your more frequently used tags related unanswered questions. From the docs,

> > Note that just because a question has an answer, that does not mean it is considered answered. While the rules are subject to change, at
> >     this time a question must have at least one upvoted answer to be
> >     considered answered.
>
> This method corresponds roughly with the unanswered ""my tags"" tab.
>
> This method request an access_token.

Apart from that, the way @Bentaye pointed out above looks correct.